# The installation of Windows Universal app ends with 0x80070002 error code

Tags: windows-store, win-universal-app, windows-dev-center

Windows Universal passes the certification in Dev Center, but installation in Store app ends with 0x80070002 error code. What can cause it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the App Package passes the certification in Dev Center it does not mean Store installs it on every Windows device. The installation may fail by 0x80070002 error. This means that some App Package component is missing. This may be caused by missing asset, like Splash Screen image in some scale. Visual Studio will not let you know that mandatory asset is missing and Dev Center omits this check.

Answer (score 0):

Base on my experience, network issue or firewall issue.

What I did is: change the Ethernet to Wifi, restart, disable the Firewall, then everything works fine.